# how to get double object using json or jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I tried out to get double DataTable from webservice by json or jquery ajax like

The WebService Method :

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet FareAccpted_(string custId)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    List<fareAccptedList> details = new List<fareAccptedList>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))

    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_FareAcceptedC", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = custId;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

The Js page :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../lpService.asmx/FareAccpted_",
    data: JSON.stringify({ custId: custId_ }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Length : '+data.d.length)

    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("FareAcceptedC" + "Error");
    }
});
```

DataTables stores in DataSet.

Comment: You tried and... what happened? Please add a lot more detail. What's the problem? What does the service do? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Sami, thanx to your valuable response, I edit my question properly again you can see and help me, Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your $.ajax call is wrong, specifically the way you are passing through the `custId_` parameter. Also the `dataType` is not used in the POST call and the `contentType` can be excluded as well.

Change your $.ajax call like this and you will now be able to hit a breakpoint in the `[WebMethod]`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../lpService.asmx/FareAccpted_",
    data: { "custId": custId_ },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Length : ' + data.d.length)
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("FareAcceptedC" + "Error");
    }
});
```

Secondly, look at the way you're instantiating the `SqlConnection` object:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))
```

"..." is not a valid connection string.You need store the connection string to your SQL database in the `Web.config` file like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=UsersDatabase;Data Source=MyServerName"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And access it from C# code like this:

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

}
```